# Find word in word document using

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document contains some percentage numbers. For eg, This month return is 1.25%". I want to highlight the percentage number with yellow background colour.

Comment: Can you precise a bit your goal and the content of your document? lenght of document, are there a lot of digits in it? Do you want to highlight them all or just the ones with % ? Also, what have you tried/done so far?

Comment: I want to highlight all the digits and it is 10 page document. I tried to find the "%" in the document, but dont know how to select the entire digit(1.25%).

Answer (score 1):

The following code looks for the pattern *1 or 2 digit(s)* followed by a *dot* followed by *1 or 2 digit(s)* followed by the *%* and highlight it (for example 1.2% , 1.23%, 12.3% or 12.34%):

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.Highlight = True
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2}%"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

This one looks for the pattern *1 or 2 digit(s)* followed by the *%* and highlight it (for example 1%, 12%):

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.Highlight = True
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "[0-9]{1,2}%"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

Hope this covers your need

**EDIT:**
If you also want to highlight negative signs in front of numbers I propose you this way in order to avoid copying the code again and again:

```
Public MyPattern As String

Sub MainSub()

    MyPattern = "[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2}%"
    HighlightPattern

    MyPattern = "[0-9]{1,2}%"
    HighlightPattern

    MyPattern = "-[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2}%"
    HighlightPattern

    MyPattern = "-[0-9]{1,2}%"
    HighlightPattern

End Sub

Sub HighlightPattern()

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.Highlight = True
With Selection.Find
    .Text = MyPattern
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Remi, can I add the negative number in the find text?

Comment: Here we look for text characters so you cannot really consider positive or negative numbers but look at it in terms of characters: You can do it by adding the _minus sign_ in the argument in the `.Text` part: giving you: `"-[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2}%"` and `"-[0-9]{1,2}%"` In that case you will have to replicate the code paragraphs. A good way would be to write only one paragraph with a variable the `.Text` argument

Comment: [Please accept this answer if it suited you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)